# iOS Configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: ios, gcc, clang, jailbreak

I have an iPad Pro 9.7 iOS 16.4.1 palera1n rootful jailbreak. I want to build gcc for it using clang 14, but when I run ./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ I get the error that I wrote in the title. Clang 14. What should I do? I want to get Simh and box64 and gcc on my iPad. I am attaching the config.log file. Thank you, I'm almost a complete zero in all this)

config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure CC=/usr/bin --target=arm-apple-darwin22.4.0 --enable-languages=c,c++

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = iPad-Ivan
uname -m = iPad6,3
uname -r = 22.4.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:41:20 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.102.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_S8000

/usr/bin/uname -p = arm
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:41:20 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.102.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_S8000
Kernel configured for up to 2 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: arm64 (arm64 v8)
Processors active: 0 1
Primary memory available: 1.92 gigabytes
Default processor set: 265 tasks, 1093 threads, 2 processors
Load average: 2.81, Mach factor: 0.44
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin/X11
PATH: /usr/bin/X11
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2381: checking build system type
configure:2395: result: arm-apple-darwin22.4.0
configure:2442: checking host system type
configure:2455: result: arm-apple-darwin22.4.0
configure:2475: checking target system type
configure:2488: result: arm-apple-darwin22.4.0
configure:2542: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2610: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2621: checking whether ln works
configure:2643: result: yes
configure:2647: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2651: result: yes
configure:2658: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2722: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:2731: checking for gawk
configure:2747: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2758: result: gawk
configure:3238: checking for libatomic support
configure:3248: result: yes
configure:3257: checking for libitm support
configure:3267: result: yes
configure:3276: checking for libsanitizer support
configure:3282: result: no
configure:3295: checking for libvtv support
configure:3301: result: no
configure:3425: checking for libphobos support
configure:3431: result: no
configure:4131: checking for gcc
configure:4158: result: /usr/bin
configure:4387: checking for C compiler version
configure:4396: /usr/bin --version >&5
./configure: 1: eval: /usr/bin: Permission denied
configure:4407: $? = 126
configure:4396: /usr/bin -v >&5
./configure: 1: eval: /usr/bin: Permission denied
configure:4407: $? = 126
configure:4396: /usr/bin -V >&5
./configure: 1: eval: /usr/bin: Permission denied
configure:4407: $? = 126
configure:4396: /usr/bin -qversion >&5
./configure: 1: eval: /usr/bin: Permission denied
configure:4407: $? = 126
configure:4427: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4449: /usr/bin    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: 1: eval: /usr/bin: Permission denied
configure:4453: $? = 126
configure:4491: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4496: error: in `/private/var/mobile/Documents/huinya/gcc-releases-gcc-13.2':
configure:4498: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_AR_set=''
ac_cv_env_AR_value=''
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_AS_set=''
ac_cv_env_AS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=''
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=''
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_CC_set='set'
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/usr/bin'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=''
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=''
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=''
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=''
ac_cv_env_DSYMUTIL_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_DSYMUTIL_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_DSYMUTIL_set=''
ac_cv_env_DSYMUTIL_value=''
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_GDC_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_GDC_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_GM2_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_GM2_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_LD_set=''
ac_cv_env_LD_value=''
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=''
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=''
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=''
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=''
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_NM_set=''
ac_cv_env_NM_value=''
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=''
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=''
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=''
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=''
ac_cv_env_OTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_OTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_OTOOL_set=''
ac_cv_env_OTOOL_value=''
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=''
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=''
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=''
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=''
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=''
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=''
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=''
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=''
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=''
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=''
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=''
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=''
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=''
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=''
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=''
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=''
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=''
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=''
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set='set'
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=''
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=''
ac_cv_host='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
ac_cv_path_SED='/usr/bin/sed'
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK='gawk'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC='/usr/bin'
ac_cv_target='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
acx_cv_prog_LN='ln'

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='gawk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='/usr/bin'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CPP_FOR_BUILD=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DSYMUTIL_FOR_BUILD='$(DSYMUTIL)'
DSYMUTIL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GDB_TK=''
GDC=''
GDCFLAGS=''
GDC_FOR_BUILD='$(GDC)'
GDC_FOR_TARGET=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GM2_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
HAVE_CXX11=''
HAVE_CXX11_FOR_BUILD=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL=''
OTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PGO_BUILD_GEN_CFLAGS=''
PGO_BUILD_LTO_CFLAGS=''
PGO_BUILD_USE_CFLAGS=''
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='./configure CC=/usr/bin --target=arm-apple-darwin22.4.0 --enable-languages=c,c++'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='/usr/bin'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-libcpp build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='arm'
build_libsubdir='build-arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
build_noncanonical='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
build_os='darwin22.4.0'
build_subdir='build-arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='apple'
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libcody libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl libiconv libctf libsframe texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gdbserver gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools libcc1 gm2tools gotools c++tools'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_host_zlib_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
get_gcc_base_ver=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='arm'
host_libs_picflag=''
host_noncanonical='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
host_os='darwin22.4.0'
host_shared=''
host_subdir='host-arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
isllibs=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
target_alias='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-libffi target-libobjc target-libada target-libgm2 target-libgo target-libphobos target-zlib target-rda'
target_cpu='arm'
target_noncanonical='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
target_os='darwin22.4.0'
target_subdir='arm-apple-darwin22.4.0'
target_vendor='apple'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='/dev/null'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

I want to build gcc for it using clang 14, but when I run ./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ I get the error that I wrote in the title